# How to get page state in webview

Tags: android, webview, status

In my Android app, I have need to show a webpage in a WebView, using the URL obtained from my server. However, it sometimes shows OK but sometimes shows an error page (a .NET-style yellow page stating "Server Error in /Web Application").

I want to do something in my app to identify that error and redirect to another page, but how do I recognize the error?

Comment: Sorry for I was too eager to know the answer,should I delete the first question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to retrieve HTML content from WebView (as a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264162/how-to-retrieve-html-content-from-webview-as-a-string)

Check the [HttpResponse code](http://cdrussell.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-get-body-of-http-response-as.html) and see if there's error returned.

Take note of the comment to avoid consuming double of the bandwidth required, make a HttpRequest and load it into the WebView if there's not error.