# Can´t get the entire HTML code from WebView Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

this is my first question here and I write it because I haven´t found anything about this.

I´m doing my final thesis and I want to do an Android app that basically does a web scraping from university´s server (with Jsoup), takes the subjects scores from a student and show them.

I´m using Eclipse Kepler as framework and testing the app in an Android 4.2.2 emulator.

For access to the server I use a WebView hidden by a LinearLayout both in a FrameLayout.
It logs in into the server by filling out the login form with JavaScript, but when it extracts the HTML code from the page and save it in a String, it doesn´t get the entire HTML. I´ve tried with document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML; document.documentElement.innerHTML; and document.documentElement.outerHTML with the same result.

Here is the WebView code:

```
private final String loginPV = "https://www.upm.es/politecnica_virtual/login.upm";
private String usuario;
private String password;
private WebView navegador;
public static boolean login;
public static String marks_html;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gestor_pv);
    navegador = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    usuario = extras.getString("user");
    password = extras.getString("pass");
    login = false;

    navegador.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    navegador.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "GETNOTAS");

    navegador.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {     
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {          
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
              if(!login){                                           
                view.loadUrl("javascript:{" +                   
                        "document.getElementById('user').value = '"+usuario +"';" +
                        "document.getElementById('pass').value = '"+password+"';" +         
                        "document.getElementById('form_login_enviar').click();" +
                        " };");
                login = true;
            }else if(login){
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.GETNOTAS.processHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
            }
       }
    });
    navegador.loadUrl(loginPV);
```

Here is the JavaScript interface:

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface {           
    Context mContext;

    MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        marks_html = html;
    }       
}
```

And here is the HTML obtained:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="https://www.upm.es/politecnica_virtual/principal.upm">
<title>Politécnica Virtual</title>
<meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="Language" content="ES">

<link rel="shortcut icon"
href="comun_publica/grafica/comunes/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="comun_publica/estilos/politecnica_movil.css">

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script
src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="zoom: 1;" class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true"
    data-url="/politecnica_virtual/principal.upm" tabindex="0"
    class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" style="min-height: 460px;">
    <form id="f" action="/politecnica_virtual/principal.upm?16_13_1693"
        method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="text/html"
        data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c" class="ui-header ui-bar-c"
            role="banner">
            <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">
                <img src="comun_publica/grafica/comunes/logo_movil.png" alt="PV">
            </h1>
            <a data-theme="b" data-icon="delete"
                href="comun_publica/varios/cierresesion.upm?UPMSSID=32l0ntbeklovmqom0fmp8jkgo2"
                class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left"
                data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true"
                data-wrapperels="span"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span
                    class="ui-btn-text">Salir</span><span
                    class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
            <h2 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Alumno</h2>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
            <input type="hidden" name="carpeta_activa" id="carpeta_activa"
                value="F"> <input type="hidden" name="UPMSSID" id="UPMSSID"
                value="32l0ntbeklovmqom0fmp8jkgo2"> <input type="hidden"
                name="accion" id="accion" value="16_13_1693"> <input
                type="hidden" name="accion_anterior" id="accion_anterior"
                value="16_13_1693"> <input type="hidden" name="idioma"
                id="idioma" value="">
            <!-- Menu Seccion -->
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="d"
                class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true"
                    data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"
                    data-theme="c"
                    class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-first-child"><div
                        class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                            <a href="#/politecnica_virtual/principal.upm&amp;ui-page=0-21"
                                class="ui-link-inherit"><span>Mis Datos</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div></li>
                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true"
                    data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"
                    data-theme="c"
                    class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li"><div
                        class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                            <a href="#/politecnica_virtual/principal.upm&amp;ui-page=0-17"
                                class="ui-link-inherit"><span>Utilidades</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div></li>
                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true"
                    data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"
                    data-theme="c"
                    class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li"><div
                        class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                            <a href="#/politecnica_virtual/principal.upm&amp;ui-page=0-6"
                                class="ui-link-inherit"><span>Formación</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div></li>
                <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true"
                    data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right"
                    data-theme="c"
                    class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-last-child"><div
                        class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                        <div class="ui-btn-text">
                            <a href="#/politecnica_virtual/principal.upm&amp;ui-page=0-3"
                                class="ui-link-inherit"><span>Atención al usuario</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Menu Seccion Cierre -->
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
                <!-- Informacion Principal -->
                <div id="informacion_principal">
                    <!--Una consulta-->
                    <!-- Cabecera de Seccion -->
                    <h2>Tablón de notas</h2>
                    <!-- Cierre Cabecera de Seccion -->

                    <!-- Contenido de la Seccion -->
                    <h3 class="destacado_flecha_naranja">Información. Tablón de
                        notas</h3>

                    <div class="separador_inferior">
                        <link rel="stylesheet"
                            href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet"
                            href="comun_publica/estilos/jquery_modificaciones.css">
                        <input type="hidden" name="filtro_expediente_mio"
                            id="filtro_expediente_mio" value="67100"> <input
                            type="hidden" name="filtro_plan_mio" id="filtro_plan_mio"
                            value="59SC"> <input type="hidden" name="filtro_codnum"
                            id="filtro_codnum" value=""> <input type="hidden"
                            name="confirma" id="confirma" value="N"> <input
                            type="hidden" name="tipo_revision" id="tipo_revision" value="">
                        <p>En esta pantalla se pueden consultar las calificaciones
                            provisionales de las asignaturas matriculadas en el año
                            académico en curso.</p>
                        <p class="advertencia">Para consultar calificiaciones
                            definitivas de convocatorias finalizadas puede hacerlo desde la
                            opción "Mis Datos - Expediente".</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="contenido_seccion" class="separador_inferior">
                        <h3 class="destacado_flecha_naranja">Asignaturas en las que
                            está matriculado en 2013-14</h3>
                        <p>A continuación puede ver todas las convocatorias
                            disponibles para las asignaturas que usted tiene matriculadas. A
                            medida que vaya superándolas se irán eliminando de la lista.</p>
                        <table data-role="table" class="ui-table ui-table-reflow">
                            <caption>CONVOCATORIA DE FEBRERO</caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Asignatura</th>
                                    <th style="width: 10%;">Nota</th>
                                    <th style="width: 46%;">Información</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Asignatura</b>MICROPROCESADORES<br>Laboratorio:
                                        Superado</td>
                                    <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Nota</b>1.7 (S)</td>
                                    <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Información</b><a
                                        href="javascript:document.getElementById('fichero').value='2013142272FEB.pdf';document.getElementById('f3').submit();"
                                        class="descarga_pdf ui-link">Descargar examen</a><br> <strong>Fecha
                                            límite para solicitar revisión:</strong> 27/01/2014 00:00 <br>
                                        Ha finalizado el plazo para solicitar revisión.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table data-role="table" class="ui-table ui-table-reflow">
                            <caption>CONVOCATORIA DE JULIO</caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Asignatura</th>
                                    <th style="width: 10%;">Nota</th>
                                    <th style="width: 46%;">Información</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Asignatura</b>ELECTROMAGNETISMO
                                        Y ONDAS</td>
                                    <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Nota</b></td>
                                    <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Información</b></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><b class="ui-table-cell-label">Asignatura</b>MICROPROCESADORES</td>
                                    <td colspan="2" style="font-style: italic;"><b
                                        class="ui-table-cell-label">Nota</b>Está línea será eliminada
                                        si supera la asignatura en la convocatoria anterior.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <div style="display: none;">
                            <!-- placeholder for modal_solicitud_online -->
                        </div>


                        <form id="f3" name="f3"
                            action="/politecnica_virtual/comun_publica/varios/descarga.php"
                            method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" id="fichero" name="fichero" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" id="dir" name="dir" value="actas">


                            <!-- Cierre Contenido de la Seccion -->
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Cierre Informacion Principal Cierre -->
            </div>

            <form id="form_webmail"
                action="/politecnica_virtual/comun_publica/varios/urlcorreo.upm"
                target="_blank" method="post" data-ajax="false">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="UPMSSID" id="UPMSSID"
                        value="32l0ntbeklovmqom0fmp8jkgo2">
                </fieldset>
            </form>

        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Content Cierre -->
    <!-- Pie de Pagina -->
    <div data-role="footer" style="text-align: center;"
        class="ui-footer ui-bar-a" role="contentinfo">
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true"
            class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-mini"
            aria-disabled="false" data-disabled="false" data-shadow="false"
            data-corners="true" data-exclude-invisible="true"
            data-init-selector=":jqmData(role='controlgroup')">
            <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls">
                <!-- Acceso a Webmail -->
                <a
                    href="javascript:document.getElementById('form_webmail').submit();"
                    data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"
                    data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"
                    class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-first-child"><span
                    class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Webmail</span></span></a>
                <!-- Acceso a Webmail Cierre -->
                <a
                    href="javascript: document.getElementById('carpeta_activa').value='S';document.getElementById('accion').value='19_7_379'; document.getElementById('f').submit();"
                    title="Buscar en el directorio" data-role="button"
                    data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true"
                    data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a"
                    class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-a ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all"><span
                    class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Directorio</span></span></a>
                <a
                    href="javascript: document.getElementById('carpeta_activa').value='S';document.getElementById('accion').value='27_2_388'; document.getElementById('f').submit();"
                    title="Cambio de contraseña" data-role="button"
                    data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true"
                    data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn...
```

It ends with ...  and don´t know why.
Is there any solution?

Sorry if it´s a silly question :)

Comment: Try the following links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264162/how-to-retrieve-html-content-from-webview-as-a-string 
or

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview

or

http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/

Answer (score 0):

You could either parse it as XML with the SAX Library available in java or read it as a file.

```
URL fileloc = new URL("url");
File html = new File(fileloc);
```

Alternatively if you want to prefetch the data while the webpage is loading and get the file from a URL(EditText)

```
//From onclick listener
EditText url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
String hfile = url.getText().toString();
MyWebView.loadUrl(hfile);
URL html = new URL(hfile);
File file = new File(html);
```

Then just echo out the html as a string.