# Form does not send data to e-mail

Tags: android, html, forms

I'm trying to send the data of this form to my e-mail, but nothing happens. How can I fix it? I'm new at this programming language and I would love some guidance!

```
<title>Solicitud de Vendedor Honorario</title>

<form action="mailto:erocha@newenergypr.com" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#FF8000"><h2>Solicitud de Vendedor Honorario</h2></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Adiestramiento</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#1B4F72">
        <select name="yesno" id="yesno" size="1">
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>  


    <tr><td bgcolor="#D4D4D4">Nombre:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="nombre" size="14"></td></tr>
```

...

```
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#FF8000"><h2>Disponibilidad de tiempo</h2></td></tr>

    <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><b>Domingo</b></td>
      <td bgcolor="#D4D4D4"><b>Desde:</b><select id="domingodesde" size="1">
        <option value="0">No disponible</option>  
      <option value="00">00:00am</option>
      <option value="01">01:00am</option>
      <option value="02">02:00am</option>
```

...

More of those, exactly the same but for the other weekdays... Now checkboxes:

```
<tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#F1C40F"><b>Ponce</b></td>
      <td bgcolor="#D4D4D4">
        <input type="checkbox" id="arr" value="arroyo">Arroyo<br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="coa" value="coamo">Coamo<br>


    <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
```

The app looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIQMS.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbDkx.jpg

Once submited, all the data that was selected should be sent to an e-mail.

Comment: There is a form close tag?

Comment: if i understood are displaying this form in a webview and  you want to send data when you perform some action on form??

Comment: You mean </form> in the end? Yes, of course.

The app looks like this: 
imgur.com/2hiUPKw
imgur.com/LEEjryD

Once submited, all the data should be sent to an e-mail. Name, time availability and the cities chosen on the checkboxes.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I see now that the info you are trying to receive is from a webview. If so you can retrieve the info from your webview as such. Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264162/how-to-retrieve-html-content-from-webview-as-a-string). After which you will have to parse content from the string.

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.document.body.outerHTML})();", 
  new ValueCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onReceiveValue(String html) {

      }
  });
```

Comment: Using an xml parser? For what? You didn't understand the problem at all.

Comment: then explain more. you have an additional two people who commented also not knowing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm not the OP. You really always have problems reading posts?

Comment: Guys, its me that wants help, sorry for not being very clear. I'm not an experienced programmer but I'm trying to learn more.

Comment: I don't know if I would need that XML parser, is there a simpler way to do it?

The app looks like this:

http://imgur.com/2hiUPKw
http://imgur.com/LEEjryD

Once submited, all the data should be sent to an e-mail. Name, time availability and the cities chosen on the checkboxes.