# Can I save a webpage created via webview in my application separately?

Tags: android, html, web

Can I save a web page generated via webview in my application separately? The storage here refers to the storage of text in the currently visible web page as text. I know that you can save the current page as an html file by pressing "ctrl + s" on one webpage on your computer. I wonder if there is a way for the webpage generated by webview in the application to be the same way on the computer.

Save files may be saved only as non-html characters.

Comment: You can get whole text of html in webview as a string and then save it in SharedPreferences/SQLite.

Comment: how to get whole text of html in webview as a string?  ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264162/how-to-retrieve-html-content-from-webview-as-a-string